# How can i use two on blur events for one textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, onblur

So i have 2 on blur events that check for different things, but the browser only recognizes the first one and disregard the second, how can i fix that?

```
<input type="text" name="first" onblur="validator()"; onblur="alpha(this)"; />
```

Thats what i have tried so far. I have also tried without the semicolons but no luck.

Comment: the semicolons go inside the quotes. But also, you should be using addEventListener/attachEvent to add listeners to DOM elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use like this,

`onblur="validator(); alpha(this);"`

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Just like this.

```
<input type="text" name="first" onblur="validator() ; alpha(this)"; />
```